# Replace Image name with Another image name in Vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

i have two folder like folder A and Folder B , Now Folder A as blank image and folder B as set of images and folder b images will be loaded to picturebox using vb .net .Now the task is i need to add button named as Replace , this replace button will replace the current image in picture box to blank image which is located in folder A, now folder A blank image name  must be changed to folder B current image name , these all must be done in Vb.net .

this is my first experience about asking the question in stackoverflow can you guys help me!

thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you include the code you've tried so far and specifically where you're having an issue?

Comment: sorry bro its our office code so iam not able to attach the code here.

Comment: We'd need some code to try help you. At least you should include details of what you've tried conceptually and what it is or isn't doing.

Comment: Are you saying that images in FolderB should be shown and images in FolderA are not shown? And then, when some button is clicked, the currently displayed image should be moved from FolderB to FolderA?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As i read through the question, my understanding is this:

```
Folder A:
- blank.jpeg

Folder B:
- rnd1.jpeg
- rnd2.jpeg
- rnd3.jpeg
```

Assuming you have made it this far that on your application load, your folder B images or one of the images is loaded into the picture box.

```
Picture box shows:
- rnd2.jpeg <-- (from folder B)
```

Now where you press the `Replace` button and it does this:

```
Folder A:
- rnd2.jpeg <-- where the picture is still blank just renamed

Folder B:
- rnd1.jpeg
- rnd2.jpeg
- rnd3.jpeg

Picture box shows:
- rnd2.jpeg <-- (from folder A, which at this point is blank image)
```

My rendition of the code:
You have to have two buttons and a picture box on your form/application.

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO
Imports System.IO

Private Sub LoadImageIntoPictureBox(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    'load image button
    'load images files paths into list

    Dim folderB = IO.Path.Combine(SpecialDirectories.Desktop, "B")

    Dim ListOfImages As New List(Of String)

    For Each image In IO.Directory.GetFiles(folderB)
        ListOfImages.Add(image)
    Next

    'creates random number generator to select one picture randomly
    Dim rnd = New Random()

    'select image from the list randomly
    Dim randomImg = ListOfImages(rnd.Next(0, ListOfImages.Count))
    PictureBox1.Load(randomImg)

End Sub

Private Sub ReplaceImageInFolderA(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    'replace button 

    'get the name filename and location from picture in picturebox
    Dim currentPicPath = PictureBox1.ImageLocation
    Dim currentPicName = Path.GetFileName(currentPicPath)

    Dim folderA = IO.Path.Combine(SpecialDirectories.Desktop, "A")

    'get the first and only file from folderA - gets fullpath of the file
    Dim blankImg = IO.Directory.GetFiles(folderA)(0)

    'rename the file in folderA with the name of currentPicName

    My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(blankImg, currentPicName)


End Sub
```

Other than this we really need to see your code.